# Build RTSP server using ONVIF for camera

Tags: camera, embedded, streaming, onvif, rtsp-server

I have a graduation project with topic:Build RTSP server for camera using ONVIF.
I'm wondering where to start.Which library, which open source, which framework should I use? What do I need to do to get started? Thank you for everyone's help.

I'm reading the documentation about RTSP and ONVIF. I'm looking forward to getting the results for a project report, I don't have much time so please show me a simple way to get started.